# Remove warning for package "was not injected in your file" when using Grunt?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I have "angular-i18n" installed as a bower dependency.

When I run `grunt serve` or `grunt build` I have receive warning:

> angular-i18n was not injected in your file. Please go take a look in
>   "/$APP_ROOT/bower_components/angular-i18n" for the file you need, then
>   manually include it in your file.

How can I remove this message?

Does making grunt insert this file into my index.html remove this warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Background**

It appears that your [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) tasks are using [`wiredep`](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) to look at your [Bower](http://bower.io) dependencies and inject the tags for loading their associated files (`link` for CSS, `script` for JS, etc) into your HTML.

`wiredep` does this by looking at the `bower.json` file on your project to figure out what you need, then looking in the `bower.json` file of each dependency to figure out what they need, and so on. Having developed a dependency tree, `wiredep` uses the [`main` property in the `bower.json`](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#main) files to determine what files from each needed package should be linked into your HTML.

When a package does not have an appropriate bower configuration (missing `bower.json` or missing/improper `main` property), `wiredep` warns you about that problem so that you know it couldn't automatically add what you need. In other words, it's telling you that not all assets have been added to your built HTML, and that you need to manually intervene to add what's missing.

**General solution**

Generally, there is nothing you can do in your own code to correct this. Manually linking the file in your HTML (outside of the `wiredep` marked areas so as to avoid having it overwritten) will ensure your project works. `wiredep`, however, will always warn you when it runs because the package itself still has the problem. You'd need to open an issue to the owner of the problem package in order to ask them to correct their packaging meta info.

**The project you're having issues with**

I [searched bower for the `angular-i18n` package](http://bower.io/search/?q=angular-i18n) and found that the project is hosted at https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n . If you look at [`angular-i18n`'s `bower.json`](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/bower.json) you can see that it is missing the `main` property. This is why the warning is being issued.

As it turns out, though, it seems appropriate that this project does not offer a `main` property. The [documentation for `angular-i18n`](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/README.md) shows that you should `bower install` it, then manually link to the file that is appropriate for *your desired locale*. It would not be appropriate for this package to list a `main` file because it provides many files, none of which should be dictated as necessary by the package--it's a developer choice.

**A possible solution for this case**

If the warning really bothers you, or you do not like the need to manually link to the file, you could fork this package to your own GitHub account and modify the `bower.json` file to point `main` to the file you want loaded. Then you would remove `angular-i18n` as a dependency for your project, and add your fork's repo as a dependency instead.

*Caveats:*

1. This may cause issues keeping up to date if you are unfamiliar with maintaining Git repos/forks.
2. This will only work if `angular-i18n` is listed as an explicit dependency of your own project and is *not* being loaded in as a dependency for another project. If another project is loading this package, you'd have to start forking projects all the way down the tree such that you could override the configuration of each.

**All in all, in this case it's probably best to manually link to the file you want and ignore the warning.**

Comment: Another solution might be to follow the steps below (grunt example, sorry for the poor formatting):

1. Change your grunt configuration to exclude the angular-i18n component

    wiredep: {
      target: {
        src: 'YOUR_PATH/index.html',
        ignorePath: 'YOUR_IGNORED_PATH',
        exclude: [/angular-i18n/, ... ]
      }
    },

2. Include the files manually

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error message using angular-i18n in a yeoman project. The wiredep grunt task makes this error message. There are 2 solutions:

**1. Exclude angular-i18n and include the file manually in the index.html**

*Gruntfile.js*

```
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
    exclude: [
      'bower_components/angular-i18n'
    ]
  }
}
```

*index.html*

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

or:

**2. Override/Set main attribute of bower_components/angular-i18n/bower.json**

*Gruntfile.js*

```
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
    overrides: {
      'angular-i18n': {
        'main': 'angular-locale_de-de.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I choose to go with the second option overriding the main attribute. This way in the index.html the angular-i18n library still gets automatically injected by the grunt task.